# want to add new value in an array but can't getting the code

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, replace, push

Given the following JSON-formatted string, write a snippet of code using JSON and array methods, to change the score in Physics to 97, remove the item for Chemistry and add an item for Biology with score 78, and another item for Geography with score 88 in its place.

```
var scores = `

    [

        { subject: 'Math', score: 89 },

        { subject: 'Programming', score: 100 },

        { subject: 'Physics', score: 95 },

        { subject: 'Chemistry', score: 75 },

        { subject: 'History', score: 59 },

    ]

`;
```

as above mentioned I have to repalce some values and add value. but I'm not getting right code about how to add the Geography with score

## I'm trying the following code to Add the Subject

```
var score = `[
    { subject: "Math", score:89 },

    { subject: 'Programming', score: 100 },

    { subject: 'Physics', score: 95 },

    { subject: 'Chemistry', score: 75 },

    { subject: 'History', score: 59 }
]`;

score = score.replace(/95/gi,97);
score = score.replace(/75/gi,78);
score = score.replace(/chemistry/gi,"Biology");

const newScore =  { subject: 'Geography', score: 88 };

const returnedScore = Object.assign(score, newScore);

console.log(score);
```

**Also tryied this formula to add but doesn't work**

```
var score = [
    { subject: "Math", score:89 },

    { subject: 'Programming', score: 100 },

    { subject: 'Physics', score: 95 },

    { subject: 'Chemistry', score: 75 },

    { subject: 'History', score: 59 }
];

delete score['3'];

console.log(score);


var newScore =`[
    


    { subject: 'Geography', score: 88 },

]`;

score.push(newScore);
console.log(score);

var scoreSetBack = JSON.stringify(score);

console.log(scoreSetBack);
```

**But it shows .push is not a function in console**
**and few other method Also tried but nothing is worked
can some help and tell what is right way to do and also check is code to replace is right**

Comment: Looks like you might want tot start by reading the documentation to familiarize yourself with working with arrays. [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [Indexed Collections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do this is by filtering the array, an example could be:

```
score = score.filter((item) => item.subject !== 'Chemistry')
```

Which will return the following filtered array:

```
score 2:  
[ 
{ subject: 'Math', score: 89 },
{ subject: 'Programming', score: 100 },
{ subject: 'Physics', score: 95 },
{ subject: 'History', score: 59 } 
]
```

As for pushing, you need to push an object similar to what's already in the array:

```
var newScore ={ subject: 'Geography', score: 88 };
```

So if we run score.push(newScore) now, Score will have { subject: 'Geography', score: 88 } on the last index

Comment: Didn't Work sir

Comment: @KaramSingh Check this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/o8w45h6n/)